# How to create a login page with dropdown list containing user id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created the controller but i am not able to compare the dropdown list selected values and textbox values with database(SQL).All the id is in dropdown list and getting retreived from database. How should i match the textbox written value

following is the HTML code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Fruit:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FruitId, Model.Fruits, "Please select")
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Quantity:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Password)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }

    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(FruitModel fruit)
            {
                fruit.Fruits = PopulateFruits();
                var selectedItem = fruit.Fruits.Find(p => p.Value == fruit.FruitId.ToString());

                return View(fruit);
            }

            private static List<SelectListItem> PopulateFruits()
            {
                List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["section"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    string query = " SELECT Section_Name,Section_password, S_no  FROM section";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (sdr.Read())
                            {
                                items.Add(new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Text = sdr["Section_Name"].ToString(),
                                    Value = sdr["S_No"].ToString()
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }

                return items;
            }
```

Comment: Didn't understand your problem much, but I think your dropdown is not getting populated, if so, you are passing fruit object, instead you need to pass fruit.Fruits to View. like instead of View(fruit) -> View(fruit.Fruits)

Comment: Actally dropdown is getting populated, and i dont know what will be the code to show the matching of dropdownlist selected value and textbox value with database

Comment: @sunnykumar HTML code?

Comment: i have updated the code bro, u can see

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: *compare the dropdown list selected values and textbox values*. Are you want to show textbox value depending on selected value from dropdown, or change dropdown selected value based from textbox?

Comment: no bro, the database is having id and password, and in the from dropdown list will be having id and the user will write the password and , then both values will be matched with the database

Comment: It depends on authentication system used to compare both ID & password against their counterparts in database. Right now you're not seen using it yet, simply returning view containing populated ID. As a side note, you should mask the password box using `type = "password"` (or `PasswordFor` helper if available).

Comment: thats what i want, how to do it, if u can share the complete code it will be helpful

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto bro, how can i connect with you , is there any way to connect with you over fb, or gmail, kindly tell

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing the value obtained from:

```
DropdownList1.SelectedValue;
```

with the value obtained from SQL using a WHERE clause.

Comment: `SelectedValue` property exist in webforms `DropDownList` control, which doesn't used here. MVC uses different way to get selected value, using model binding with corresponding viewmodel property.